# How to affect a parent process environment in Linux?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I know that a child process cannot directly affect its parent process, HOWEVER, how does a tool like [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) work? It's a CLI tool that can "instantly" switch between nodejs versions, which I think means modifying the PATH somehow to point to a different binary installed on your PC.

By "instantly" I mean that you can open a shell, run `nvm use [version]`, and the version is available to use in the same shell. How can a script change the PATH of the shell it's run on?

I've been trying to follow the source code but I'm stumped

Answer (score 3):

```
$ type nvm
nvm is a shell function from /home/jkugelman/.nvm/nvm.sh
```

A script runs in a child process and cannot change environment variables in the parent. A shell function, on the other hand, runs in the same shell and can manipulate the environment.

If you want to see exactly what it's doing use `declare -pf` (*print function*) or `which`:

```
$ declare -pf nvm
nvm () {
    # code snipped
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The command is likely a function. For example:

```
#!/bin/bash

function set_nvm() {
        PATH="$1:$PATH"
}
```

Source the above file so that the function is available in the shell. This can be done in your `.bashrc` so you don't have to manually do it every time:

```
$ . test.sh
```

Then you can call the function as it were a command:

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
$ set_nvm /tmp
$ echo $PATH
/tmp:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```